# Is there a way how to handle multiple SDL_PollEvent loops without clearing the event queue?

Tags: sdl, game-loop, sdl2

Is there a way how can I handle more `SDL_PollEvent` while loops for one `SDL Event`, without taking the events off from the event queue?

---

Let us say I have something like this:

```
void Game::processInput() {

    SDL_Event event;
    SDL_PollEvent(&e);

    Engine::InputManager::processInput(&e)

    GUI_Library::InputManager::processInput(&e);    
}
```

And then the engine processes the input in function like this:

```
    void Engine::InputManager::processInput(SDL_Event* e) {

    _mainEvent = *e;

    while (SDL_PollEvent(&_mainEvent)) {

        switch (_mainEvent.type) {

            case SDL_KEYDOWN : {

                Engine::InputManager::pressKey(_mainEvent.key.keysym.sym);
                break;
            }
            case SDL_KEYUP : {

                Engine::InputManager::releaseKey(_mainEvent.key.keysym.sym);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

However, this while loop clears the whole event queue, and another input manager (my GUI, for example) does nothing because it no longer has events in the queue.

Is there a possible way to handle this situation?

Comment: No, but you shouldn't even need this anyway. You only ever need a single main loop, period. A typical approach is to do something like `while ev = get_event() { input.handle(ev) gui.handle(ev) whatever.handle(ev); }`, which can be generalized out with a message dispatch system or handler registry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had similar; not a huge fan of how SDL does this but nothing stops you from storing the inputs in a secondary vector. Move the loop from out of your `InputManager` upward into your `Game`, call it `Game::Loop` or `Game::ProcessEvents`. Now, as you poll/pop all events there, act on what you can (like Window-related events), but store the inputs on a public (static) vector on your own `InputManager`. Then when you call the `InputManager` to run, you can process the inputs.